# Authenticate user with YouTube API

Tags: php, api, youtube, verify

I need to verify a user's YouTube account with a PHP page. So I'm planning to let the user login with their Google-Account and check if they have a YouTube-Account, and then show a generated code.

My question: How to let the user login with their YouTube-Account? Is there any "Login with YouTube" button like the Login with Google-button on many pages? And is there any easy tutorial how to login and verify the account?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ <-- sign into Google account, from there you receive an ID, not sure if this may or may not link to a YouTube account - you'll have to research.